# How to create a deposit contract? (I need real experience in the industry!)

Tags: solidity

I am a newbie for smart contract developing.
I am trying to build a deposit contract with

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract DepositContract {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    address public owner;

    event Deposited(address indexed depositor, uint amount);
    event Withdrawn(address indexed withdrawer, uint amount);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit amount must be greater than 0");
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit Deposited(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

It seems like this is a real basic deposit contract. I guess I am missing many things. Is there anything I should keep in mind as a smart contract developer in real industry?
Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats pretty good for a noob, I would add reentrancy guard to protect functions like withdraw, gas limitation, emergency stop incase a critical bug is found and a feauture where users can earn interest on their deposit